# Single sign on for rails apps in the same domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 2 rails apps on the same domain. i want the single sign on feature to be added to them. i would prefer to maintain separate database for each app..

Can anyone please tell me how to do this?

Thanks in advance,
Ak

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look into [OpenID](http://open_id_authentication) and [RubyCas](http://code.google.com/p/rubycas-server/).

But since your apps run on the same domain you can share sessions by setting the domain name in config/environments/production.rb (assuming sub domains):

```
ActionController::Base.session = {
  :domain => ".example.org"
}
```

Don't forget to set the same session_key and secret across the apps.

```
config.action_controller.session = {
    :session_key => 'my_shared_session_key',
    :secret      => 'awesome_super_secret_key'
}
```

Comment: I am also looking into an internal system that would be single sign-on like, and considered masqerade (http://github.com/dbloete/masquerade/tree/master) as an internal OpenID server, but the learning curve I think would be high for my users (not to mention, me.)

Comment: Oh, I also have a question regarding this solution... with this only work with cookie store or will it also work with activerecord session store?